# good learning site

Tags: internet, torah-study

what is a good source for learning?

Comment: As indicated in the two recent answers, this question is too broad to be very useful, so I'm closing it.

Answer (score 5):

I just saw this this morning. It is a pretty nice list of "[Free primary Jewish sources and  resources on the Internet](https://docs.google.com/Doc?docid=0ASx6sZjO1KzmZDhwbW5jal8xZndoOHJuZ3Q&hl=en_US&ndplr=1)".

But a clarification of the question can help with what you are looking for. A site with discussions of Jewish learning topics? Primary sources?

Comment: Don't expect clarification from the asker at this point. He never registered his account and posted this months ago.

Comment: ... now featuring J.SE in the "Discussion Boards" section! :)

Answer (score 4):

http://www.kolhashiurim.com/New/HomePage/NewDefault.aspx?Lang=Hebrew&English=True

Answer (score 4):

I don't know your level so here is a list:

1. http://www.hebrewbooks.org contains 49,000 books in English and Hebrew in OCR.
   (intermediate-advanced)
2. http://www.haoros.com/ for in-depth Hebrew pilpulim (advanced).
3. http://www.sichosinenglish.org Chassidus in English (beginners to intermediate)
4. http://www.Chabad.org has a library with some classical sfarim, as well many articles. (beginners to intermediate)

For audio:

1. http://www.chassidus.com has many audio shiurim in Yiddish/Hebrew/English. (advanced)
2. http://www.mp3shiur.com/ has many Halacha and Gemarah shiurim
3. http://torahlectures.com/
4. http://www.kolhalashon.com

Comment: This answer is *very* Chabad-oriented. Even the haoros.com site linked to is a Chabad site. (NTTAWWT.)