# Where can I find audio-book sefarim?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, recording

I want to be able to learn while I am doing the dishes, and as much as the shiurim available online are great, I would like to find online shiurim which are just recordings of someone reading sefarim, preferably without translating them.  I have some specific ones in mind, but if there is a database with a selection of any significant size, that would be the best.

Does anyone know where I can find online (or, failing that, orderable) audio-book sefarim?

A point of clarification:  I would prefer a database with multiple works, but even references to audio of single works would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47692/5323

Comment: I don't know what [this is](http://www.teachittome.com/seforim2/audio.html), but it turned up in a Google search and looks relevant

Comment: Basically, sefarim-on-tape. Perhaps try organizations that have resources for the blind.

Comment: If you want to hear Chumash, you can find *plenty* of recordings of *leining* around the internet -- you could even make your own!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's an Israeli resource out there with all of Tanach read aloud.

Comment: @Shokhet, among other things, it's the source for the lyrics of the popular song ["*Bilvavi*"](http://www.zemirotdatabase.org/view_song.php?id=15).

Comment: @IsaacMoses I don't understand; are you referring to my first comment, or my second? ( *I'm leaning toward first* )

Comment: @Shokhet, sorry; the first one. The lyrics come from *Sefer Hachareidim*.

Comment: @IsaacMoses My comment was a little unclear; I know what the sefer is (though I didn't know that "Bilvavi" came from there); I was saying that the posted link *looks* like someone reading a sefer, but I'm not sure -- it might actually be a series of shiurim on the sefer. I haven't listened to any of those audios, but since they're set up like to ToC of a sefer, that it looks like it might be what YeZ is looking for.

Comment: [Quite related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97509/are-there-any-audio-recordings-of-the-gemara)

Answer (score 3):

This actually does exist on [Kol Halashon](https://www.kolhalashon.com/New/Ravs.aspx?Lang=Hebrew&Path=Hebrew%7CHGmr%7CGemaraLimud%7CR2343-1&English=True)!
The man who recorded this, Rav Yehoshua Leibowitz, has also recorded quite a few other areas of text that may be of interest:

- Shulchan Aruch
- Tanach
- Rambam
- Select Mussar Seforim
- Ein Yaakov/Some Yerushalmi
- Prayers/other odds and ends