# Are there any audio recordings of the Gemara?

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara

[929 Project](https://www.929.org.il/pages/aboutEN.html) has recordings of Tanach in which a voice actor reads the given chapter of Tanach in the original Hebrew with intonations that fit the subject matter ([example](https://m.soundcloud.com/929-bible/rpptqabi0dht?in=929-bible/sets/ezqrzojzlg96)).

This can be useful for many reasons, among them is that it can serve as an auditory review which does not require stationary book reading.

Are there any such [similar] recordings for the Gemara? Recordings which contain a reading of the content (presumably with some intonations) but nothing else.

The point of this would be the same, a method of review which does not require stationary book reading.

Comment: You mean specifically without translation?

Comment: Generally the  Gemara is sufficiently complex that people prefer explanation with it. Here for example is a set of recordings of *lectures* of the entire thing with translation, explanation, and commentary; given daily over a 7-year period ("daf yomi", a page a day) in Los Angeles in the 80s-90s. https://www.dafyomi.org/download.php

Comment: How is that different from the boundless other Dafyomi shiurim? Which is Not what I’m looking for @Shalom

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel sorry -- just one I found easily online. Apologies for not understanding your question.

Comment: That guy should really be leining it...  the trop is there for a reason.

Comment: The guy in my answer does lain it. The point of that 929 project is a little removed from that of laining @Heshy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually does exist on [Kol Halashon](https://www.kolhalashon.com/New/Ravs.aspx?Lang=Hebrew&Path=Hebrew%7CHGmr%7CGemaraLimud%7CR2343-1&English=True)!
Seems to be as described — a man reading the Gemara in *Daf* format, said in ‘traditional’ Ashkenazi Gemara tone.

---

As a side note, the man who recorded this, Rav Yehoshua Leibowitz, has also recorded quite a few other areas of text that may be of interest:

- Shulchan Aruch
- Tanach
- Rambam
- Select Mussar Seforim
- Ein Yaakov/Some Yerushalmi